# Making normal generic class

Tags: java, javafx

I have many controller classes. And in each such class I'm using folliwng code many times:

```
tc_mt_buy_amount.setCellFactory(param -> {
            return new TableCell<FaClConversionDeals, BigDecimal>(){
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(BigDecimal item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if(empty || item == null){
                        setText("");
                    } else {
                        setText(df.format(item));
                    }
                }
            };
        });

tc_mt_sell_amount.setCellFactory(param -> {
            return new TableCell<FaClConversionDeals, BigDecimal>(){
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(BigDecimal item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if(empty || item == null){
                        setText("");
                    } else {
                        setText(df.format(item));
                    }
                }
            };
        });
```

In order to not dublicate code so many times in each class, I've created an inner classes in each controller class:

```
tc_mt_buy_amount.setCellFactory(param -> {
                return new FormatMainColumn();
            });
tc_mt_sell_amount.setCellFactory(param -> {
            return new FormatMainColumn();
        });

private class FormatMainColumn extends TableCell<FaClConversionDeals, BigDecimal> {

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
        @Override
    protected void updateItem(BigDecimal item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if(empty || item == null){
            setText("");
        } else {
            setText(df.format(item));
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in order to not to write inner classes in each controller, I want to create standalone generic class to where I can refer from each controller. The problem is that, for instance, `FaClConversionDeals` in above example is different in each controller (i.e., it may be other classes). In structural way, it should look similar to this:

From controller:

```
tc_mt_buy_amount.setCellFactory(param -> {
                    return new FormatMainColumn(ClassName);
                });
```

Generic Class:

```
 private class FormatMainColumn(ClassName class) extends TableCell<ClassName, BigDecimal> {

                DecimalFormat

 df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
            @Override
        protected void updateItem(BigDecimal item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if(empty || item == null){
                setText("");
            } else {
                setText(df.format(item));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how the generics syntax works. If I understood you correctly, you want your class declared as

`private class FormatMainColumn<T> extends TableCell<T, BigDecimal> {`

and then you can do `return new FormatMainColumn<ClassName>();`.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for such simple question

Comment: Well, generics aren't necessarily easy.